# How do you connect your backend to front end

Tags: python, flask

My group and I are working on a project to create a website that shows the trend of commercial fishing for certain species over the span of 50+ years. We have our code in python listed below that analyzes our data set and we want to connect it to our website using flask. Any tips on how we would do that?

```
from ast import Lambda
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import flask
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX

# Load the data set from the special file.
data = np.load('FishData.txt.npy')

# Test: Did everything load?
data

# Separate the data by species. Each new array should only contain data
# about the particular species.
species = ['CRAB, BLUE', 'TUNA, YELLOWFIN', 'SNAPPER, RED', 'SHRIMP, ROCK',
       'MACKAREL, KING']

# These return the rows containing the indicated species.
crab = np.where(data[:, 2] == species[0])
tuna = np.where(data[:, 2] == species[1])
snap = np.where(data[:, 2] == species[2])
shrimp = np.where(data[:, 2] == species[3])
mack = np.where(data[:, 2] == species[4])

# Now separate.
crab_data = data[crab, :]
tuna_data = data[tuna, :]
snap_data = data[snap, :]
shrimp_data = data[shrimp, :]
mack_data = data[mack, :]

# These are the rows that correspond to an animal being fished in
# that state.
TX = [np.where((data[:, 1] == 'TEXAS') & (data[:, 2] == species[j]))
for j in range(0, 5)]

MS = [np.where((data[:, 1] == 'MISSISSIPPI') & (data[:, 2] == species[j]))
for j in range(0, 5)]

AL = [np.where((data[:, 1] == 'ALABAMA') & (data[:, 2] == species[j]))
for j in range(0, 5)]

LA = [np.where((data[:, 1] == 'LOUISIANA') & (data[:, 2] == species[j]))
for j in range(0, 5)]

FL = [np.where((data[:, 1] == 'FLORIDA-WEST') & (data[:, 2] == species[j]))
for j in range(0, 5)]

np.array(data[TX[0], 0], dtype = int)
np.array(data[TX[0], 3], dtype = int)

# Variable for labels.
species_labels = ['Blue Crab', 'Yellowfin Tuna', 'Red Snapper', 'Rock Shrimp',
              'King Mackarel']

# Labels.
xlab = 'Year'
ylab = 'Yield, in pounds'

# Plot the counts.
# First, for Texas.
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot()
for k in range(0, 5):
  plt.scatter(np.array(data[TX[k], 0], dtype = int), 
     np.array(data[TX[k], 3], dtype = int),
     label = species_labels[k])

plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.xlabel(xlab)
plt.ylabel(ylab)
plt.title('Yield of commerical fishing in Texas')
# ax1.ticklabel_format(style = 'plain')
plt.show()

# Other states follow.
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot()
for k in range(0, 5):
  plt.scatter(np.array(data[MS[k], 0], dtype = int), 
     np.array(data[MS[k], 3], dtype = int),
     label = species_labels[k])

plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.xlabel(xlab)
plt.ylabel(ylab)
plt.title('Yield of commerical fishing in Mississippi')
# ax2.ticklabel_format(style = 'plain')
plt.show()

fig3 = plt.figure()
ax3 = fig1.add_subplot()
for k in range(0, 5):
  plt.scatter(np.array(data[AL[k], 0], dtype = int), 
     np.array(data[AL[k], 3], dtype = int),
     label = species_labels[k])

plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.xlabel(xlab)
plt.ylabel(ylab)
plt.title('Yield of commerical fishing in Alabama')
# ax3.ticklabel_format(style = 'plain')
plt.show()

fig4 = plt.figure()
ax4 = fig1.add_subplot()
for k in range(0, 5):
  plt.scatter(np.array(data[LA[k], 0], dtype = int), 
     np.array(data[LA[k], 3], dtype = int),
     label = species_labels[k])

plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.xlabel(xlab)
plt.ylabel(ylab)
plt.title('Yield of commerical fishing in Louisiana')
# ax4.ticklabel_format(style = 'plain')
plt.show()

fig5 = plt.figure()
ax5 = fig1.add_subplot()
for k in range(0, 5):
  plt.scatter(np.array(data[FL[k], 0], dtype = int), 
     np.array(data[FL[k], 3], dtype = int),
     label = species_labels[k])

plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.xlabel(xlab)
plt.ylabel(ylab)
plt.title('Yield of commerical fishing in Florida')
# ax5.ticklabel_format(style = 'plain')
plt.show()

# As not all species are represented equally in each split,
# we aim to train a few time series models (likely ARIMA) to
# forecast future yields for blue crab and red snapper.

# We first split the data into a training set and a testing
# set. Train up to 2005, and test afterwards.
train = np.array(np.linspace(0, 55, 56), dtype = int)
test = np.array(np.linspace(56, 71, 16), dtype = int)

# Gather training data.
TX_crab_train = data[TX[0], 3][:, train]
TX_snap_train = data[TX[2], 3][:, train]

MS_crab_train = data[MS[0], 3][:, train]
MS_snap_train = data[MS[2], 3][:, train]

AL_crab_train = data[AL[0], 3][:, train]
AL_snap_train = data[AL[2], 3][:, train]

LA_crab_train = data[LA[0], 3][:, train]
LA_snap_train = data[LA[2], 3][:, train]

FL_crab_train = data[FL[0], 3][:, train]
FL_snap_train = data[FL[2], 3][:, train]

# And now the testing data.
TX_crab_test = data[TX[0], 3][:, test]
TX_snap_test = data[TX[2], 3][:, test]

MS_crab_test = data[MS[0], 3][:, test]
MS_snap_test = data[MS[2], 3][:, test]

AL_crab_test = data[AL[0], 3][:, test]
AL_snap_test = data[AL[2], 3][:, test]

LA_crab_test = data[LA[0], 3][:, test]
LA_snap_test = data[LA[2], 3][:, test]

FL_crab_test = data[FL[0], 3][:, test]
FL_snap_test = data[FL[2], 3][:, test]
```

We set up flask and our virtual environment and are just having trouble how to configure the code and what the syntax would look like.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Flask has solid documentation for [creating a simple API](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) and [how to consume it in JS](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/javascript/).

This would produce two simple, easier to write apps. Your API for serving the data and a simple HTML/CSS/JS webpage for requesting and displaying data from the API.